# Reinitialize an init.m file without rebooting Mathematica

Tags: menu

I placed the following code in a init.m notebook that executes upon Mathematica startup.  This creates a shortcut menu command that allows me to insert a page break by pressing Control+p. You can see the shortcut in the insert menu dropdown.

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",{MenuItem["Page Break",FrontEnd`KernelExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True],After]],FrontEnd`MenuKey["p",FrontEnd`Modifiers->{"Control"}],System`MenuEvaluator->Automatic]}]];
```

Let's say I want to change the shortcut from Control+p to Control+l. If I run the init.m file again with the modified code while Mathematica is already running it keeps the old shortcut which I don't want.  You can see both by clicking the insert drop down menu.

Is there a way to erase the first shortcut by executing the init.m file without rebooting Mathematica?  That is is there a command I can put at the top the init.m file that will erase the previous version?

I want to reinitialize so that erases the previously executed shortcut and installs the new one without rebooting? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this from John Fultz via [MathGroup Archive.](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00400.html)

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic}]]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I placed your code in the init.m file at the top and tried executing without rebooting Mathematica.  It did not erase the old command in the insert menu.  I then tried executing the code in a regular notebook but had the same result.  It doesn't seem to reset the commands i created using the AddMenuCommands functions.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain That's unfortunate; I seem to remember this working in the past but I didn't test it at this time.  I shall try later, but I am (still) using version 10.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: No problem.  Yes, by the link you sent it did seem to work in earlier versions.  I am running 11.3 on a mac running 10.14.3